# backbonejs history, different root for different pages

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am developing a multi-page application. On some pages, I need a navigation without refreshing the page. Use the library and Backbone.js Require.js. I can not understand how can I change the 'root' parameter in the line, depending on the specific page.

```
Backbone.history.start ({pushState: true, root: '/settings/'});
```

For example I need to hash #help worked only on an URL **hostname/settings/#/help**, and if it is called **hostname/#/help**, that did not work rout

Structure of the application case on this lesson: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

That is, I need a different option 'root' for certain pages, but how to do it in the existing architecture, I can not understand I hope for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse the page url and then set root accordingly.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var root;

switch (path) {
    case '/settings/':
        root = path;
        break;        
    default:
        root = '/';
}

Backbone.history.start ({pushState: true, root: root});
```